# Initialize object in parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement a like feature. I have a label and a button. If the button is pressed it should add one vote to **Parse** and the label would retrieve the number of votes. However it does not work with my code. It looks like I need to initialize parseObject but I don't know how to. my code for the cell is below. Thank you. I have been stuck for this problem for days.

```
import UIKit
import ParseUI
import Parse

var parseObject:PFObject?
var votes = [PFObject]()

class NewCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
var parseObject = PFObject(className: "Posts")
    @IBOutlet weak var postsImageView: PFImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var votesLabel:UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        postsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    }


    @IBAction func vote(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (parseObject != nil) {
            if let votes = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
                parseObject!.setObject(votes + 1, forKey: "votes")
                parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
                votesLabel?.text = "\(votes + 1) votes"
            }
            else {
                parseObject!.setObject(1, forKey: "votes")
                parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
                votesLabel?.text = "1 votes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have implement you target method. I am not sure whether it will save the object or not when you pass in `nil`. For making it consistent, you better include `target` and `selector` because it will also tell you whether the object is saved successfully. You can also go to the **Parse** dashboard to check whether it's saved successfully or not.

And yes, you have not instantiate your object. Otherwise, your `if-else` statement just got executed and did nothing. If you try to debug it, the parseObject is actually `nil`. In **Parse**, there are several ways to do and docs provides you everything: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/objectWithClassName:

Comment: Thank you I have initialized it with the help of user below but  I now get an error at if (parseObject != nil) saying could not find overload for != that accepts the supplied arguments.

Comment: You just need to instantiate before using it, other of your codes are not necessarily to change.

Comment: Do you mean this code     `var parseObject = PFObject(className: "Posts")` I have added this code and gives me an error

Comment: I believe that syntax error can be figured by yourself. The error you made from the code I saw is not being instantiated properly.

Comment: So     `var parseObject = PFObject(className: "Posts")` is wrong?

Comment: The problem for your question is not being instantiated correctly. As long as you add the code you showed, it will be working fine. But I don't know what's your other errors if you don't post the codes. And I think syntax error can be solved by yourself.

Comment: Yes I would like to know how to initiate correctly. I am using swift and the docs are all obj-c.  I am stuck and can't find any places that show how to initiate. This is all my code for cell view

Comment: I am telling you the code you just added is correct. And now you should be able to call `setObjectKey`.

Comment: OK thank you. I would try to resolve the syntax error.

Comment: We have no way to help you if we don't see your codes. This problem is what it's. You have to instantiate before using it.

Comment: Ok I have added the initiate code to question. My syntax error is on         `if (parseObject != nil) {` stating that  could not find overload for != that accepts the supplied arguments